# Why does this code not give expected output?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database

I was experimenting with database operations. For example,

```
begin
   db_con = PG.connect :dbname => 'sureshkumar', :user => 'sureshkumar'
   db_con.prepare 'get_result', "SELECT * from users;"
   users_name = db_con.exec_prepared 'get_result'
   if users_name != nil
       puts users_name.values
   else
       puts "There is no users available in the table users"
   end
rescue PG::Error => e
        puts e.message
ensure
        db_con.close if db_con
end
```

The table `users` contains only two columns. They are,

```
user_id
user_name
```

If the table does not contain any row, the `exec_prepared` statement does not return any row. In this case, why does the if condition not become false? How do I check if the `exec_prepared` method doesn't return any row?

Comment: don't you need a password to connect? What happens if you write simply `if users_name`, omitting the `!=nil` part?

Comment: I did not set the password for the database. So, I don't need password to connect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`users_name = db_con.exec_prepared 'get_result'` will never return `nil` to `users_name`.

According to the documentation of [`PG::Connection#exec_prepared`](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/ged/ruby-pg/PG/Connection:exec_prepared) it will return `PG::Result` object. So, `users_name` object can never be `nil`. It will always be an instance of `PG::Result`.

So, to check whether you have any rows returned from the query execution you need to check if this `PG::Result` object has any values in it. In your case, `users_name` variable contains the `PG::Result`. So you will have to call `ntuples` on it so see how many rows are returned from the query.

so change your if clause to something like:

```
if users_name.ntuples > 0
  puts "There are users"
else
  puts "There is no users available in the table users"
end
```

See [`PG::Result`'s documentation](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/ged/ruby-pg/PG/Result#ntuples-instance_method) to know what other methods you can call on it to access the result.